# Create User and su in Dockerfile

Tags: docker, su

Trying to create a new user foo with

```
adduser --disabled-password --gecos "" smarthome
```

I trie to su to that user
`su foo`, what does not work (whoami is still root).

I think that the ENTER is missing (empty password).

How can I change to the new user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`USER`](https://docs.docker.com/reference/dockerfile/#user)

> ```
> USER <user>[:<group>]
> ```
>
> or
> USER UID[:GID]
>
> The `USER` instruction sets the user name (or UID) and optionally the user group (or GID) to use as the default user and group for the remainder of the current stage. The specified user is used for `RUN` instructions and at runtime, runs the relevant `ENTRYPOINT` and `CMD` commands.